# Reduce height of div uniformly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In fiddle im attempting to reduce the height of a css class :

http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/76/

I'm reducing the height of class pds-vote :

```
.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
    height:20px !important;
}
```

But the height is not being reduced uniformly. The height below the vote button is less than the height above it, can the ehight be reduced uniformly so that there is an equal amount border above and below the vote button ?

Code behind fiddle :

```
.pds-question-top {
font-size:10pt !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-pd-link, .pds-comments {
display:none !important;
}

.pds-box {
width:220px !important;
}

.pds-input-label {
width:85% !important;
}

.PDS_Poll {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-answer-span {
color:#00f;
}

.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
}

.pds-answer-text {
color:#00f;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-answer-feedback {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-votebutton-outer {
text-align:center;
}

.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pds-input-label,.pds-answer-input {
float:left;
}

.pds-view-results,.pds-links {
color:#FFF !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-comments,.pds-return-poll {
color:#FFF !important;
}

.pds-links {
    display: inline !important;
}
.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-question-top {padding:0 !important}

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 15px;float:left">Header</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `line-height` to the same value as `height` and remove any padding. That way, the content is *vertically centered*, which makes for the height to be distributed uniformly: http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/77/.

```
.pds-vote {
    background-color: #424242;
    height: 40px !important;  /* 20px does not fit the contents */
    line-height: 40px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Vote button is taller than 20px, that's why the button overflows your "centered" container.

Instead of setting a height for `.pds-vote`, reduce the padding for it's container.

```
.pds-vote {
    background-color: #424242;
}
#PDI_container6352993 .pds-vote {
    padding: 4px 0px;
}
```